# Как удалить тэг  в строке?

Tags: javascript, строки

Есть строка "`текст текст текст <br> текст текст`".
Строка - переменная яваскрипт. Как можно удалить тэг переноса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например так:

```
var product = "текст текст текст <br> текст текст";
var product = product.replace("<br>","");
```

Другой вариант:

```
var product = document.getElementById('pr_title_one').textContent;
```

И еще:

```
var product = document.getElementById('logo-sub').innerHTML.replace("<br>", " ");
```

Comment: Что-то у меня не работает. У меня скрипт берёт содержание дива.   var product = document.getElementById('pr_title_one');
  product = product.replace("<br>","");
        alert(product.innerHTML);

Comment: var product = document.getElementById('pr_title_one').textContent;

Comment: тогда не потребуется ничего заменять

Comment: Почему-то всё-равно не работает. У меня при   var product = document.getElementById('pr_title_one');

        alert(product.innerHTML); выводится текст с тэгом. А когда дописываю .textContent; пишет андефайнд

Comment: alert(product)

Comment: да, так работает. Спасибо.